# Let $V$ be a vector space. Prove that the doubleton set $S = \{u, v\}$ is linearly dependent if and only if $u$ is a scalar multiple of $v$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I prove by contradiction. We assume that $S$ is linearly dependent, but $\vec{u}$ is not a scalar multiple of $\vec{v}$ and show that this leads to something completely and utterly ridiculous!

If $\vec{u}$ is not a scalar multiple of $\vec{v}$, we have $\vec{u} \ne c\vec{v}$, for $c \in \mathbb{R}$

Since $S$ is linearly dependent we have $a\vec{u} + b\vec{v} = 0$ where $a,b$ are not both zero. But this implies that $\vec{u} = (-\frac{b}{a})\vec{v}$  and since $-\frac{b}{a}\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $a,b$ except $a = 0$ $\vec{u}

$\vec{u}$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec{v}$ when $a\ne0$. This is a contradiction.

But we must still deal with the case $a = 0$. So $a = 0$ implies that $b\ne0$ else $S$ would be linearly independent. So this must mean that $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$

But $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$ is not a contradiction as $\vec{u} \ne 0\vec{v}$ for all $\vec{u}$ for example, if we have $\vec{u} = (1,1,1)$ and $\vec{v} = (0,0,0)$ $\vec{v}$ and ${\vec{u}}$ are linearly dependent but $(1,1,1)$ can never be a scalar multiple of $(0,0,0)$ beacause this would imply that $1/c = 0$...

I am not sure if I am missing something logic wise. But should the question not ask to prove iff either $u$ or $v$ are multiple of each other. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The original statement is wrong and you've identified it.  The correct version of the statement would be that $S=\{u,v\}$ is linearly dependent if and only if $u$ is a scalar multiple of $v$ **or $v$ is a scalar multiple of $u$**.

The problem is that when $v=0$, the pair is linearly dependent, but $u$ might not be a scalar multiple of $v$.